# Hash method in Laravel

Tags: hash, laravel-4

I have a question concerning the Hash::make method in Laravel 4.2 .. I've notice that it returns always a different string for the same value . So I am wondering if this affects If I want to look for a user using his email and hashed password in the table . If it's not ? Why I have then this issue of not getting a user with correct credentials from the table using the where statements (where email and where password) ? but when I look for it using just the email it works .. I am 100% convinced it's just about the Password . What do you think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get different hashes on purpose, the function adds a random salt to each hashed password. This is important to get secure hashes.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = Hash::make($password);
```

The verification cannot be done in the SQL statement directly, instead you can search for the user by username/email, get the stored password-hash, and afterwards verify the entered password with the password-hash from the database.

```
// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = Hash::check($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```